# Customizing facebook comments

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, facebook

I am developing a website wherein I want to use the facebook comment plugin, and I want to customize comments' CSS. I am using `ASP.NET MVC` architecture and my page requires that I send the href for the fb:comments via ViewData. Due to this I am adding my facebook comments tag using javascript to a div in my page.

I am trying to Customize the `CSS` by referring 
http://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-customize-the-facebook-comments-social-plugin-on-a-static-fbml-tab/
but it seems by `CSS` is not being applied to my facebook comments section.

The Code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    Url = '<%=ViewData["Url"] %>';
    Xid = '<%=ViewData["Xid"] %>';
    document.getElementById('fb_comments')
            .innerHTML = "<fb:comments href=" 
              + Url 
              +"num_posts=\"4\" xid=" 
              + Xid + " width=\"350\"></fb:comments>";

});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
#fb_comments {
width: 350px;
float: left;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #909090; 
min-height:850px;
height:100%;
background-color: #E8E8E8;
 }

#fb_comments a {
    color: #909090;
}

</style>
</head>
<body style="width:350px;">

<div>       
    <div id="fb-root">           
    </div>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1">
    </script>
    <div id="fb_comments">                      
    </div>        
</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [comment by the post's author at the bottom](http://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-customize-the-facebook-comments-social-plugin-on-a-static-fbml-tab/#comment-7805).

> HI, to our knowledge, you cannot style the regular facebook comments anymore. If anyone knows how to, please share here.